# Compare unsigned with signed (int and short) in C

Tags: c

Hello i have tried to understand the output of the following code in C but i dont get why x is x greater than y i.e why is x > y?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   short a = -2;
   unsigned short b = -a;
   int x = -2;
   unsigned y = -x;

   if(a<(unsigned short)b)
       printf("a < b\t");
   else
       printf("a >= b\t");

   if((unsigned)x<y)
       printf("and x < y\n");
   else
      //my problem is here
       printf("and x >= y\n");
}
```

```
output : a < b and x >= y
```

Comment: Try printing `(unsigned)x` (`printf` flag is `%u`).

Comment: `x` is not `> y` because `x` is negative. But `x` cannot be cast to `unsigned` without changing its value in some way. You basically told the compiler to ignore the fact that `x < 0` and use some other value, which will follow its type conversion rules.

Comment: To `<` compare a _signed_ with _unsigned_: `a < 0 || (unsigned) a < b`.

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam do not edit question this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void){
   short a = -2;
   unsigned short b = -a;
   int x = -2;
   unsigned y = -x;

   printf("a = %hd\n", a);
   printf("b = %hu\n", b);
   printf("x = %d\n", x);
   printf("y = %u\n", y);
   printf("(unsigned)x = %u\n", (unsigned)x);
   if(a<(unsigned short)b)
       printf("a < b\t");
   else
       printf("a >= b\t");
   if((unsigned)x<y)
       printf("and x < y\n");
   else
       printf("and x >= y\n");
}
```

the answer will be obvious. Why `(unsigned)x` is such a big number. It is because the `x` is a [two's complement number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). `-2` in this format is `0xfffffffe`

Comment: `(unsigned short)b` does not change the type of `b` as it is `unsigned short`.  So why cast?  Just echoing OP's code?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I did not even notice that. Just added the `printf`s. You would notice that before not very fortunate @AbhilekhGautam edit